# How to use DpapiSymmetricCryptoProvider with Cryptography encryption block?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, enterprise-library

I am using cryptography application block. and configure DpapiSymmetricCryptoProvider. but there is not option to store key file. So from where it will get the key and in load balancing how will we handle it?

Thanks,
Girish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a provider that requires a key to your configuration (pick Add Symmetric Algorithm Provider), the configuration tool starts the Cryptographic Key Wizard. It will allow you to generate a new key and save it to a file and to set the appropriate values in the configuration. 
For more inforation, see this [chapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953194%28PandP.50%29.aspx), specifically the Configuring Cryptographic Providers section.